# Align div to image-border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to ask if it's possible to create 'transition' between two images like this: [image: transition between images]
using css/javascript?

The thing on top is a div with it's content and background image (sand/water) and i have some other div on bottom (also with some content and background-image) that needs to be split using that 'wave' (which is .png file).

Things i tried to do was using 'wave' as a border-image, which obviously didn't work. I found out that i probably have to use tools like http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ to create some shapes for both top and bottom divs, but it's going to take a lot of time and may not be responsive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You simply need to use **[multiple background stacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)**.

e.g.

`background: url('images/wave.png') no-repeat center, url('images/beach.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;`

Where the wave png file must have its semi-transparency so it can show the beach below it.

---

> **EDIT:** The aim of OP's question is to clip the image so that it can take only the wave's area. That is achievable trough the use of `clip-path`. More information about this can be found at **[CSS Tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. But i don't think i explained my problem correctly. Thing you showed works, however i need the 'wave' to somehow limit the bottom or top div background. So as you can see in my question, the background is only expanded as far as the wave is.

Comment: @Macjej , the `clip-path` way of doing things is only partially-supported by some browsers, this is not a good practice for now. Judging by your screenshot, you just need to spread the wave image across your main beach container.

Comment: So probably the best way will be to combine wave to top or bottom background in gimp or something. Okay, thanks for your time!

Comment: I am not saying you shouldn't use this, go ahead and try it out, but if this is not a crucial part of your project I wouldn't suggest adding such a complex approach to it.

Comment: Understood. I won't do that then. I'll just merge those backgrounds in gimp or something. One more time: thank you.